# Create El Capitan's bootable USB drive using Windows

Tags: usb, macos, bootable-disk

As I say in the title, I need to create a bootable USB drive with OSX El Capitan using Windows 10.

I can't start my Mac using OSX anymore and I want to perform a clean install. If I use Recovery my OS will be restored via internet, and it would be Mountain Lion. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Yes that is what I want to avoid: download ML, install it, downoad EC, re-format SSD, install EC. I have a very slow internet connection and I really don't want to format my disk too much times. The TransMac tool seems useful, I'll give it a try

Comment: There's no format between the 2 downloads, it's install & update.